# whats equivelent to : Request::route()->parameters[1] in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code in L3 :

```
Request::route()->parameters[0];
Request::route()->parameters[1];
```

Whats is that equivalent in laravel 4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all parameters and then use the index:

```
$parameters = array_values(Route::current()->parameters());

echo $parameters[0];
echo $parameters[1];
```

(`array_values` is needed because otherwise `$parameters` is an associative key value array)

Or if you know the actual name of the route parameter you can simply use `Route::input()`:

```
echo Route::input('first');
echo Route::input('second');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

There is no `route()` method on the `Request` class in the L4.2 docs.

There is however `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameters()` which may be able to do what you want.

Comment: yes but the route() got different parameters , how does Route::currentRouteName() relate to that?

Comment: Edited, pasted wrong snippet.  See more here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2919